# Use of instance member 'meow' on type 'Cat' did you mean to use a value of type 'Cat' instead?

Tags: swift

This is one of those problems that makes me go "How do I even?"

This is the compiler error I'm getting:

`Use of instance member 'getAttackUPSequence_Frames' on type 'SKFootmanSprite' did you mean to use a value of type 'SKFootmanSprite' instead?`

I'm getting this for all my _Frames variables.
Here are my public properties for SKFootmanSprite:

```
// ATTACK
static let attackUp_Frames = getAttackUPSequence_Frames()
static let attackDown_Frames: [SKTexture] = getAttackDOWNSequence_Frames()
static let attackLeft_Frames: [SKTexture] = getAttackLEFTSequence_Frames()
static let attackRight_Frames: [SKTexture] = getAttackRIGHTSequence_Frames()

static let attackUpRight_Frames: [SKTexture] = getAttackUPRIGHTSequence_Frames()
static let attackUpLeft_Frames: [SKTexture] = getAttackUPLEFTSequence_Frames()

static let attackDownLeft_Frames: [SKTexture] = getAttackDOWNLEFTSequence_Frames()
static let attackDownRight_Frames: [SKTexture] = getAttackDOWNRIGHTSequence_Frames()
```

This is one of the functions that gets an attack up sequence:

```
func getAttackUPSequence_Frames() -> [SKTexture] {
    var textures = [SKTexture]()
    for var i = 1; i < 7; i+=1 {
        let imageName = "footman_attack_up0" + String(i)
        textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName))
    }
    let imageName = "footman_up_stand"
    textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName))
    return textures
}
```

I'd like my sprite frames to use `let` instead of `var`. 
(The official Swift textbook from apple put a lot of emphasis on using `let` instead of `var` for things like this.)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `let` variables are static, but your function is not.

You should try by making your function `getAttackUPSequence` static.

That error means just that, that you're trying to access an instance member (the function) from "outside" the instance.

Answer (score 0):

yeah，your function getAttackUPSequence should be static.